# Scipy Krylov Space variation

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix, eigenvalue, arpack

I am validating my stability code written in python and I need to prove that my eigenvalues are not `Krylov` size dependent. I am using `scipy.sparse.linalg.eigs()` routine and I would like to know if I can show converging of eigenvalues with varying `Krylov` sub-space size. I played with the `tol` and `maxiter` settings, however, for my particular problem the leading eigenvalue was always the same, even with extreme values like `tol=1` and `maxiter=2`. Is there a direct way I can manipulate `Krylov` in `SciPy.sparse.linalg.eigs()`?

I tried varying "maxiter" and "tol" for an eigenvalue problem with k=5 and all 5 of the eigenvalues never changed even with extreme values of "maxiter" and "tol"